# Existing Cinemachine Virtual Camera Settings conflicts with my existing Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cinemachine virtual camera that attach to my player and this is the settings

[Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqnWt.png)

The output of this setting is it follows the model without rotating the camera and thats what I need. Now I added this script

```
`using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrbitalTest : CinemachineExtension {
    private const float RotateSpeed = 2f;

    private Vector2 _currentRotate;
    private Vector3 _distanceVector;
    private float _currentDistance = 3f;
    private Transform _lookAt;

    private CinemachineVirtualCamera _virtualCamera;

    private void Update() {
        HandleInput();

        // Rotate the camera
        var centerMatrix = Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(_currentRotate.y, _currentRotate.x, 0f));
        _distanceVector.z = -_currentDistance;
        var pos = centerMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(_distanceVector);

        // Update camera position and orientation
        _virtualCamera.transform.position = _lookAt.position + pos;
        _virtualCamera.transform.LookAt(_lookAt.position);
    }

    private void HandleInput() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) Rotate(new Vector2(1f, 0f));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) Rotate(new Vector2(-1f, 0f));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) Rotate(new Vector2(0f, 1f));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) Rotate(new Vector2(0f, -1f));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) Scale(-0.1f);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) Scale(0.1f);
    }

    private void Rotate(Vector2 diffDelta) {
        diffDelta *= RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 30;
        _currentRotate.x += diffDelta.y;
        _currentRotate.y += diffDelta.x;
    }

    protected override void ConnectToVcam(bool connect) {
        base.ConnectToVcam(connect);
        if (!connect) return;

        _lookAt = GameObject.Find("LookAt")?.transform;
        if (_lookAt == null) {
            _lookAt = new GameObject("LookAt").transform;
            _lookAt.position = new Vector3(0f, 0.5f, 0f);
        }

        _virtualCamera = VirtualCamera as CinemachineVirtualCamera;
        _virtualCamera.LookAt = _lookAt;
    }

    protected override void PostPipelineStageCallback(CinemachineVirtualCameraBase vcam,
        CinemachineCore.Stage stage, ref CameraState state, float deltaTime) {
        var (pos, rotate) = GetTransform(_virtualCamera.LookAt.localToWorldMatrix);
        state.RawPosition = pos;
        state.RawOrientation = rotate;

        // Look at the player's position
        _virtualCamera.transform.LookAt(_lookAt.position);
    }

    private (Vector3 pos, Quaternion rotate) GetTransform(Matrix4x4 baseCenterMatrix) {
        var centerMatrix = baseCenterMatrix * Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.AngleAxis(_currentRotate.y, Vector3.up) *
                                                               Quaternion.AngleAxis(_currentRotate.x, Vector3.right));

        _distanceVector.z = -_currentDistance;
        var pos = centerMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(_distanceVector);

        return (pos, centerMatrix.rotation);
    }

    void Scale(float delta) {
        _currentDistance += delta;
    }
}`
```

Now it overrides my existing settings in the inspector. How can I prevent it? Even just dont make the camera rotates when the player rotates

I tried modifying the code but fails. What I want to happen is that it will not override my settings

Update

This code

```
protected override void PostPipelineStageCallback(CinemachineVirtualCameraBase vcam,
        CinemachineCore.Stage stage, ref CameraState state, float deltaTime) {
        var (pos, rotate) = GetTransform(_lookAt.localToWorldMatrix);
        state.RawPosition = pos;
        state.RawOrientation = rotate;
    }
```

This is the code that causes the rotation. If i remove it the zoom and scale doesnt work

Comment: The Inspector your are showing is of the `Cinemachine` component right? You didn't add your extension under `Add Extensions` right?